# How to find pages with tag?

Tags: java, aem

```java
JSONArray pagesArrayFromMethod = new JSONArray();

    private void getListOfChildPagesWithTagAsJSON(Page page) {
        try {
            Iterator<Page> childPages = page.listChildren();
            while (childPages.hasNext()) {
                Page childPage = childPages.next();
                JSONObject pageObject = new JSONObject();
                if (Arrays.asList(childPage.getTags()).contains("customtag")) {   // here is problem
                    pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath());
                    this.pagesArrayFromMethod.put(pageObject);
                }
                Iterator<Page> childPagesOfChildpage = childPage.listChildren();
                while (childPagesOfChildpage.hasNext()) {
                    getListOfChildPagesWithTagAsJSON(childPagesOfChildpage.next());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

problem = 'List' may not contain objects of type 'String'!

I have a tag and if the page has this tag it should be put in an array. But when I try to determine if there is a tag on the page, I get an error, I cannot use the method `contain` with `String`. I need to convert String into Tag or what method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The [Page APIs getTags()](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getTags--) method returns a `Tag[]` and not a `String[]` and hence you can't use `contains()` method directly.

There are a few options though.

1. Find whether the tag is present by looping through your `Tag[]`

```
Tag[] tags = childPage.getTags();
for (Tag tag : tags) {
    if ("customtag".equals(tag.getTitle())) { //Replace getTitle with getName or getTagID depending on whatever customtag refers to
        pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath());
        this.pagesArrayFromMethod.put(pageObject);
        break;
    }
}
```

2. Alernatively, you can resolve the actual tag using the [TagManager API](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html#resolve-java.lang.String-) if you have the tag ID or tag title and then use your existing logic. For e.g.

```
Tag tag = tagManager.resolve("customtag"); //or resolveByTitle() if you only know the title of the tag.

if (tag !=null && Arrays.asList(childPage.getTags()).contains(tag)) {  
    pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath()); 
    this.pagesArrayFromMethod.put(pageObject);
}
```

Please note that you need to inject the TagManager to your method to do this. You can get the TagManager from the resource resolver as shown below

```
TagManager tagManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(TagManager.class);
```

3. You can also [find all content tagged with a particular tag or a set of tags](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html#find-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) using the TagManager API. However, please note that this would return all the nodes which contains a `cq:tags` property and not just the `jcr:content` node. Hence, you may need to further filter from the results.